# Send Image in HTTP Request Body

Tags: http, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Javascript Client API To save an image to Google Cloud Storage.

The Cloud storage wants a put request to be posted to its api endpoints. I read the file from file input. It is inform of a Javascript File Object. After that the following code runs.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
reader.onload = function (e) {

  var base64Data = btoa(e.target.result);
  gapi.client.load('storage', 'v1', function () {
      var rpcRequest = gapi.client.request({
            path: '/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o',
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
              'uploadType': 'resumable',
              'name': file.name,
              'Expires': <?php echo $this->expires ?>,
              'GoogleAccessId': '<?php echo $this->accessid ?>',
              'Signature': '<?php echo $this->signature ?>'
             },
           headers: {
             'X-Upload-Content-Type': file.type,
             'X-Upload-Content-Length': file.length,
             'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
           },
       });


   rpcRequest.execute(function (jsonResponse, rawResponse) {
     var response = jQuery.parseJSON(rawResponse);
     var session_uri = response.gapiRequest.data.headers.location;
     initiateUpload(session_uri);
   });

   function initiateUpload(session_uri){
      gapi.client.load('storage', 'v1', function () {
        var rpcRequest = gapi.client.request({
        path: session_uri,
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
         'Content-Length': file.length,
         'Content-Type': file.type,
        },
        body: base64Data,
      });

     rpcRequest.execute(function (jsonResponse, rawResponse) {
       console.log(rawResponse);
     });
   });
  }

  });
                }
```

The file appears in cloud storage but is corrupted. I started debugging the HTTP requests and found that the message body for by request is different as compared to standard Google Upload request. Below are images of the request bodies.

**My HTTP PUT REQEST Body:**

[image]

**Google HTTP PUT Request Body**

[image]

The code which initiates by request in above given code is

```
                        var rpcRequest = gapi.client.request({
                            path: session_uri,
                            method: 'PUT',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Length': file.length,
                                'Content-Type': file.type,
                            },
                            body: base64Data,
                        });

                        rpcRequest.execute(function (jsonResponse, rawResponse) {
                            console.log(rawResponse);
                        });
```

I handle the file object by reading it through the reader and then encoding it

```
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
           // request preparation logic goes here.
        }
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are base64 encoding the data that you are uploading. That is not necessary. I have a suspicion that the "corrupted" file that is being stored in GCS is your actual file, only base64 encoded.